# Creating a sandbox/appdomain in asp.net web app - security issues

Tags: asp.net, security, sandbox

I'm looking to create a sandbox/appdomain in a web app so that I can execute an exe.

I've been looking at this link but it seems more than I need.

Try to even run a comand prompt is causing security issues.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046(v=vs.100).aspx

Updated:

From this link it says you can create an appdomain like this:

```
Dim sandBox As AppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("sandBox")
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/539195/Run-exe-inside-ASP-NET-and-catch-exception-using-A

..but can't seem to even get past that. I get the error..

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Thanks,

Comment: Help us a little here. What kind of issues are you running into? What kind of errors do you get? Show us your code, please. 

To look at the issue from a different perspective: Why does it have to be the EXE that generates the text? Can you compile that piece as a DLL instead, or just implement the functionality here?

Comment: Question updated. I've tried all sorts of paramaters into the createdomain function..but still get security probs..

Comment: The .exe is a third party exe that generates a code for something. It has to be used. being able to run a command prompt is something I'd like to try possibly, id I could run the exe via that.

Comment: What Trust level is configured in your ASP.NET environment?

Comment: There's none specified in the web.config. Is there a max level to allow appdomains to be created?

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure Full Trust.

Then check these threads:

[System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.EnvironmentPermission, mscorlib' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470216/system-security-securityexception-request-for-the-permission-of-type-system-se)

[Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission'](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e91bfb53-5148-4122-894c-56dc0d0b6a29/request-for-the-permission-of-type-systemsecuritypermissionssecuritypermission)